# Pushing view controller from inner view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864445/designing-a-view-controller-with-multiple-xibs), I have a view controller that needs to replace itself with a different layout in certain cases where data may not be present. This seems to work:

```
if ([analysis length] == 0) {
    hasReview = NO;
    UnreviewedSPP* unreviewedSPPView = [[UnreviewedSPP alloc] init];
    unreviewedSPPView.ProductName = self.productName;
    unreviewedSPPView.SdcId = self.sdcId;
    unreviewedSPPView.Delegate = self;
    NSArray* newViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UnreviewedSPP" owner:unreviewedSPPView options:nil];
    self.view = [newViews objectAtIndex:0];
    return;
}
```

However, it seems that I cannot push a new view controller from within the replacement view:

```
    [priceButton handleControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside withBlock:^{
        WebViewController* wv = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        wv.url = offerURL;
        [Delegate performSelector:@selector(pushViewControllerFromSubview:) withObject:wv];
    }];
```

priceButton is a custom button object that can perform a block as a target action.

I've tried multiple approaches: passing the outer view controller as a delegate and passing the outer view controller's navigation controller as a property on the inner view controller.

Nothing seems to work. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question:

1) Is wv being retained... when you call pushViewControllerFromSubview?  I notice you have an autorelease deal here.  Check the wv view within pushViewControllerFromSubview.

2) Another approach for replacing views is to use the '[self.view addSubView:myView];' and [myView removeFromSuperView];'... that may be a better approach than pushing the view controller.

Cheers

Comment: removed your signature because it's not welcome here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about adding it as a subview. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was that my "outer view" was actually a subview so I could not access its navigation controller directly. I had forgotten about that.